# Can you check an object against a type, without assigning it said type?

Tags: typescript

I think the best way to show what I mean would be with a little code sample:

```
type ObjType = {
  [prop: string]: any
}

const x: ObjType = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'test'
}

type XType = typeof x;
```

`XType` is now the same as `ObjType`, but I would like it to have the type of the actual object. But without losing the option that the object `x` has to match `ObjType`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR TS4.9+**

TypeScript 4.9 will introduce [the `satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton) which has the effect of contextually checking a value against a type without assigning it that type, so you don't need a helper function anymore.  It will look like this:

```
const x = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'test'
} satisfies ObjType // okay

type XType = typeof x;
/* type XType = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
} */

const oops = 123 satisfies ObjType; // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwCrmgXigbwFBSgbTACcB7MALigGdgiBLAOwHMBdSgQwZGwF9t+AxiQY0oADygYcedpQCMAGlxQ4lAOTAINNb2rtgdKgDM6W2IhSQoAemtQSAa3bdsoKwA1L6KG4gkj4gDc2NYAVD6oUJ6RUsoylAwArgC2cBBEwXh4qtS0jEzBPFCh1oLCoiRkVJJQcgBMAMx6Bsam1fDIqIE2dumkRACEQA)

---

**PREVIOUS ANSWER FOR TS4.8-**

By [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `x` as `ObjType`, you have made the compiler forget the specific type of its initializer.   Instead you want to *check* that your value is of a particular type without *widening* it to that type.

This is known as "the `satisfies` operator" as requested and discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) and [microsoft/TypeScript#47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920), but it has not been implemented in TypeScript directly yet.

While there is no built-in support for it, you can get this effect by introducing a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function:

```
const asObjType = <T extends ObjType>(t: T) => t;
```

The function `asObjType` just returns its input `t` without changing the type `T`, but that type is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `ObjType`.  Instead of annotating `x` as `ObjType`, we can just assign the output of `asObjType` to it.  Let's see it in action:

```
const x = asObjType({
  a: 1,
  b: 'test'
});

type XType = typeof x;
/* type XType = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
} */
```

Looks good.  And let's make sure that it doesn't allow non-`ObjType` values through:

```
const oops = asObjType(123); // error!
// ------------------> ~~~
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjType'
```

Also looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwCrmgXigbwFBSgbTACcB7MALigGdgiBLAOwHMBdSgQwZGwF9tsAxiQY0o7KvGSooGADxIoEAB7AIDACZVYiFJAB8ACmCUkAShl6owANz8hI4FCUyxEnagM487SgEYANLhQcJQA5Ko0obymttigkFAAGrroVqgkAGZOtgD0AFRpCcnSGF54YpQMAK4AtnAQRLblwZQ09My2PFB5OXbCoiRkWhjikikGvgBMAMwxUDk5ikSkRACE2AtQAIJETLVqjpmF0KHVdQ2hUHRaDCSO4lR0TAzscAA20MAkUGDsROw1CCqIhQI7xE5jVChIA)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :) Weird that this is not implemented in the language yet though.